# Get Nodes attached to all items in a path including the top element

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher query

```
MATCH p=(pInit:part{_id:'XXXXXXXXXX'})-[cons:consumes*]->(items:part) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (items)-[relmop:isMaintainedWithOp]->(mop:maintenanceOps)   
RETURN p,pInit,relmop,mop 
ORDER BY items._sequence
```

I would like to also get the 'mop' (maintenanceOps) attached to 'pInit' without having to copy the "optional match" line.
In my actual example I can have up to 6 or 7 lines like the optional Match line. If I have to copy It adds a lot of lines.

In the previous example the result I would like to avoid is the optional match line which would result in the following query:

```
MATCH p=(pInit:part{_id:'XXXXXXXXXX'})-[cons:consumes*]->(items:part) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (items)-[relmop:isMaintainedWithOp]->(mop:maintenanceOps)   
OPTIONAL MATCH (pInit)-[relmop2:isMaintainedWithOp]->(mop2:maintenanceOps)  
RETURN p,pInit,relmop,mop,relmop2,mop2
ORDER BY items._sequence
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this

```
MATCH p=(pInit:part{_id:'XXXXXXXXXX'})-[cons:consumes*]->(item:part)
UNWIND nodes(p) AS node
WITH p,nodes(p)[0] AS pInit,node,[(node)-[relmop:isMaintainedWithOp]->(:maintenanceOps) | relmop][0] AS relmop
RETURN p,pInit,relmop,endNode(relmop) AS mop,node
ORDER BY node._sequence
```

Comment: I think this alone:
```UNWIND nodes(p) AS node```
solved it. Now I need to fix how I parse the result ! 
Thank you my good friend !

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird but I fixed my problem doing this :

```
MATCH p=(:part{_id:'XXXXXXXXXX'})-[cons:consumes*0..20]->(items:part) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (items)-[relmop:isMaintainedWithOp]->(mop:maintenanceOps)   
RETURN p,pInit,relmop,mop
```

Allowing 0 connections, seems to use the first object in the path as 'items' and search for other connections.